# Is softmax "omni-periodic"?

Tags: real-analysis, discrete-mathematics, terminology, exponential-function, periodic-functions

A function is said to be "periodic" if there's a finite $T$ such that $f(t) = f(t \pm T), \forall$. Usually there's either *one* such $T$, or none at all. How about *infinitely many* $T$, that can also be *complex?*:

$$
f(t)=f(t \pm T),\ \forall t, T \in \mathbb{C} \tag{1}
$$

In some sense, [Softmax](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Softmax_function) qualifies; take any set of values, $(x_0, x_1, ..., x_{N-1})$, and add or subtract any number, real or complex, and the output's the same ($e^T$ factors from numerator and denominator).

It's easier to conceptualize if compared to a sine; with frequency $f=2$, we'd need to add (or subtract) $T=1/2$ from every input array value for every output array value to remain the same.

---

Is this interpretation sensible? Is there an entire class of such functions (with a formal name)?

To be clear, softmax cannot be directly expressed as $(1)$ since it can't directly be represented as $f(t)$, but if we assume all inputs are unique and sorted (and uniformly-spaced?), we obtain a discretization whose continuous variant may qualify for said interpretations.

---

**Test code**:

```
import numpy as np

def is_omniperiodic(fn):
    x = np.random.randn(10)
    ref = fn(x)
    for T in 100 * np.random.randn(100):
        assert np.allclose(fn(x + T), ref)

def softmax(x):
    return np.exp(x) / np.sum(np.exp(x))
```

Comment: If $\forall t. f(t)=f(t+T)$, then isn't it also true that $\forall t. f(t)=f(t+2T)$? And by induction, $\forall t. \forall N \in \mathbb{N}. f(t)=f(t+NT)$?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy Yes, that's how periodic functions are defined, except here $\forall N \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: In your question, you say that T might be complex, not the N.

Comment: Take a look at elliptic functions. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_function

Comment: Another word for equation (1) is "constant".

Comment: @MarkS. It is, if we don't bother looking further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a continuous function of a real variable, you can have one (minimal) period.  If there are two or more periods (not rational multiples of each other) your function is constant.  I do not know of any reason to study real discontinuous functions with two or more periods.

For a continuous function of a complex variable, you can have two (minimal) periods, as long as one is not a real multiple of the other.  The study known as "elliptic functions" deals with such "doubly periodic" cases.  If they are non-constant, they cannot be entire functions, but they can be meromorphic.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_periodic_function

---

I looked at the link on "softmax".  It seems to be a function on $K$-tuples to $K$-tuples like this:
$$
S(x_1,x_2,\dots, x_K) :=
\left(\frac{\exp(x_1)}{\sum_{k=1}^K \exp(x_k)},
\frac{\exp(x_2)}{\sum_{k=1}^K \exp(x_k)},
\dots,
\frac{\exp(x_K)}{\sum_{k=1}^K \exp(x_k)}\right)
$$
Now it is true that if you add the same thing $T$ to all the arguments, then the result is unchanged.
$S(x_1+T,x_2+T,\dots,x_K+T) = S(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_K)$.  But that is not what we would call "periodic".

Comment: Guess I should re-ask this question with emphasis to the paragraph beneath the question sentence as everyone seems fixated on $(1)$ - but at least "meromorphic" seems interesting.